# I having problem with section ID. I need to jump(scroll) to 'ABOUT US' section. But it keep take to the home section

Tags: html, css

Here's is my HTML code

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="banner">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo UMS"><p><a class="eng"href="#" >ENG | </a><a class="bm"href="#" >BM</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="homeabout">
    <nav style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li><a class="homestyle"href="#" >HOME </a></li> 
    <li><a href="#aboutus" class="aboutstyle" > ABOUT US</a></li> 
    <li> <a class="servicesstyle" href="#">SERVICES</a></li> 
    <li> <a class="staffstyle" href="#">STAFF</a></li> 
    </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
    <p class="wlcome"> WELCOME TO </p> 
 </div>
 <div >
    <a href="#" class="btnctc" >Contact Us</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <section id="aboutus">
    <div class="bg2"> 
    <div class="homeabout_2">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;"><li><a class="homestyle2"href="#" >HOME </a></li> 
    </ul>
    </div>
    </section>
    </div>
```

And also here the CSS. I'm don't know what I'm doing. I'm maybe have problem with the CSS. This code is for Home Page.

```
.bg
{
position: absolute;
width: 1440px;
height: 1024px;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;       
background: url(bg.jpg);
        
}
.banner
{
position: absolute;
width: 1443px;
height: 148px;
left: -3px;
top: 62px;
background: #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 14px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

And this CSS code is for the 'ABOUT US' page that I want to jump to.

```
.bg2
{
position: absolute;
width: 1440px;
height: 2024px;
left: 0px;
top: 2024px;
background: url(bg2.png);
}
```

I'm hoping someone can help me. Thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Maybe you should first run your code through a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). The nav element is not a list, so it can't have list items (li), for example. You need spaces between your class and href attributes, etc.

Comment: That being said: the link to your 'aboutus' section looks fine to me. You just won't see much happening because you don't have much content in your page yet.